# How to trigger submit form using jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, event-tracking, analytics.js

I am trying to track comments on blog posts via Google Universal Analytics.  I want the label to pick up the name of the blog post so I'm using jQuery to fire the event.

So far I have the following code (which is based on code I used for other websites and work fine) - obviously I must have overlooked something as it is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#commentform').submit(function(){
     var postname = $('h2.post-title').text();
     ga('send', 'event', 'Engagement', 'Comment', postname, 5);

   });
});
```

Any thoughts?

(Sorry I would link to the blog but it is not live yet)

Thanks

Comment: return false after ga(...);

Comment: what error do you have? what is problem? Just not working?

Comment: I think the problem is the page is refreshing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#commentform').submit(function(){
var postname = $('h2.post-title').text();
ga('send', 'event', 'Engagement', 'Comment', postname, 5);
});
});
```

First of all. This code assigns the text of a `h2` tag with class `post-title` found in the `document`. A way more reliable way to get the title of the post would be an id.

Secondly, it may not work, because the form is submited before the Google Analitycs code fires. So you should stop the default behaviour and submit the form after the analitycs finishes sending it's data. (See: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback)

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( document ).on( 'submit', 'form#commentform', function( e ) {
        var postname = $( '#post-title' ).text();
        ga( 'send', {
            'hitType': 'event',
            'eventCategory': 'Engagement',
            'eventAction': 'Comment',
            'eventLabel': postname,
            'eventValue': 5,
            'hitCallback': function() {
                //now you can submit the form
                //$('#commentform').off('submit').trigger('submit');
                $('#commentform').off('submit'); //unbind the event
                $('#commentform')[0].submit(); //fire DOM element event, not jQuery event
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Edit:**
I just realised the code from `hitCallback` might not work. The revised version should call the event of the DOM element and in result - send the form.

**Edit2:**
Corrected the event binding in case the form doesn't exist when document.ready() is fired

Comment: Thanks MythThrazz - I copied/pasted what you posted but it is still not working.  I'm not getting any error message, just no code firing.  Am I supposed to add something to it? (I added the id to the h2)

Comment: I forgot to mention that's the code for jQuery 1.9+ can/do you use it?  Also which code isn't firing? The event callback or the hitCallback?

Comment: Yeah the site used jQuery 1.9 -- the event isn't firing

Comment: If the event's isn't firing maybe there's no form with id="commentform" ? At least not on $(document).ready()

Comment: Correction - the site is now using jQuery 1.9 and everything is working fine.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't quite get it - my solution worked and you select the other answer?

Comment: Oops sorry first time user thought I could check both if both were helpful.  Yours is checked now.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without looking at an actual page, but likely the browser is redirecting to the form's submission before ga's network call is made. You'd need a way to wait for ga to finish, then finish submitting the form.

Comment: Pre-Universal Analytics, you'd have to add a delay after submitting the event. With Universal Analytics, you can specify a [hitCallback](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback) that runs after the data has been sent.